# Event corner with Calendar and custom list

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, sharepoint-calendar

I need to create a corner in intranet like in the pic below.

[image]

I am thinking to add custom tables in the page layout. Then add Calendar with with custom table, and fetch calendar data in that table !!